# Dropbox v2 API trouble with PHP CURL call not working

Tags: api, dropbox

Try to access the Dropbox v2 API calls, using PHP and a CURL call.  Based on the sandbox here https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_search, the "Show Code" looks like this.

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/search \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer myAccessTokenHere \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"path":"/My Cars","query":"\".j\"","start":0,"max_results":50}'
```

My PHP code looks like this

```
function performSearch()
{
    $cheaders = array("Authorization: Bearer myAccessTokenHere",
              'Content-Type: application/json',
              'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/My Cars","query":"\".j\"","start":"0","max_results":"50"}');

    $ch = curl_init('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/search');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cheaders);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    echo "\n response = $response";
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

When I execute it, I get

> response = {"error": "Not Found"}

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/search");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"path\":\"/My Cars\",\"query\":\"\".j\"\",\"start\":0,\"max_results\":50}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Authorization: Bearer myAccessTokenHere",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
echo "\n response = $result";
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, getting much closer than I was, but this code returns with an error, not sure which part it's talking about  -- 
 response = Error in call to API function "files/search": request body: could not decode input as JSON

Comment: The error is saying that the JSON in your request body (that is, for your parameters to the API call) is invalid. It looks like you do have an extra pair of `\"` in there. You probably meant: `"{\"path\":\"/My Cars\",\"query\":\".j\",\"start\":0,\"max_results\":50}")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers guys -- New code - works w/o getting the errors, but now I'm not getting any results returned....  I added some conversions outside the actual call so that I could see what json string were being passed in

Here's the new code

```
$path = "/My Cars";
$query = ".j";
$start = 0;
$max_results = 50;

$accessToken = $this->accessToken;
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/search");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


$arr = array('path'=>$path, "query"=>$query, "start"=>$start, "max_results"=>$max_results,   
                                    "mode"=>(array(".tag"=>"filename_and_content")));
$jArr = json_encode($arr);

$arrNull = array("body"=>"");
$jNull = json_encode($arrNull);

echo "\n\n" . $jArr;
echo "\n\n" . $jNull;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jArr);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                            "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken",
                            "Content-Type: application/json"
            ]);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
          echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
echo "\n result = $result";

return ($result);
```

Here's what I get for output - no erros BUT no content????
(I've tried different directories, in the sandbox the "/My Cars" returns 6 results)

{"path":"/My Cars","query":".j","start":0,"max_results":50,"mode":{".tag":"filename_and_content"}}

{"body":""}

result = {"matches": [], "more": false, "start": 6}

Comment: Seems that the sandbox works differently vs the actual API endpoint.  Instead of "query":",j"  I tried "query":".jpg" and that returned the 6 jpg files I have in that directory.  I also tried appending the ,  mode":{".tag":"filename_and_content"}}   but I get an error so I left it out.  Hope this thread helps someone that has been having issues with the v2 interface

Answer (score 0):

Solved - changing the $query to

$query = ".jpg";

I get results back now.

FYI: no longer required in the code above are the following lines

$arrNull = array("body"=>"");
$jNull = json_encode($arrNull);

and remove the "echo" function calls to use in production...

Thanks for helping me solve my errors, hopefully this will help someone else

John